# FB API: Create Canvas

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

How to create (new) canvas and append canvas to a Facebook page via API? I could not find this in the Facebook graph documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may edit `namespace` and `canvas_url` / `secure_canvas_url` properties of your application by issuing `POST` request to:

https://graph.facebook.com/APPLICATION_ID

Look for additional information in [documentation for `Application` object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/)